# Bad Signed JSON signature for a single app

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm working on an application that serves multiple Facebook apps from a single source. It's structured so that multiple apps can be served from multiple machines all running the same code - only the config changes per app.

Running one of these apps on my local machine works fine & running all but this one problematic app on the live server also works.

The scenario causing problems is one app running on the live server that triggers the infinite redirect loop and "Bad Signed JSON signature" spammed in the error log.

Since this is a shared codebase and the other apps all work - the logical place to look is in the config - I've checked 3 times now - the App ID, secret and redirect params are correct.

So - **Question**: Has anyone had this issue and managed to resolve it? Got any tips for me as to where I can look?

Comment: What library would be logging that error? Is that your own code, or a Facebook-provided class you're using?

Comment: Hmm, looks like a [Facebook class](http://support.roarengine.com/discussions/support/697-facebook-integration-for-iframe-apps-getting-an-oauth_token-from-a-signed-request-using-the-php-facebook-api). Have you tried searching for the error on the web, to see what other people are doing to resolve it?

Comment: The standard Facebook SDK https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/src/base_facebook.php

Comment: Yes I've searched. Hence asking on SO. The questions dealing with this error on SO do not explain the cause of it

Comment: Try to look at this [link](http://www.violato.net/blog/php/71-uncaught-curlexception-60-ssl-certificate-problem-verify-that-the-ca-cert-is-ok-when-implementing-facebook-connect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly 3 times was not enough - there was a trailing space in the app secret config file.